Can not load web page from javascript trough window.location.assign
Here is my html code, it's the homepage of my website.
<!doctype html>
<html lang="it">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height, width=device-width">
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/search.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/top_menu.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/body.css">
        <title>Hive</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav id="top-menu">
            <div class="navbar hive-item">
            <div class="logo"><a href="#">Hive</a></div>
            <ul id="top-bar-ul" class="menu">
            </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <script>
            function search() {
                let user_name = document.getElementById('user-search-input').value;
                window.location.assign('./user-search.html');
                return false;
            }
        </script>
        <div id="body-content" style="width:90%;height:auto;margin:50px auto auto auto;padding:0;">
            <form class="search" onsubmit="search()">
                <input id="user-search-input" class="input-search" type="search" placeholder="Search user..." required>
                <button type="submit">search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>


Every time I submit from the "search" form the page just reload.
If i type window.location.assign('./user-search.html') in the console it works perfectly. I'm using firefox. I looked on the web and I am still stuck. Can anyobody help me? thank you in advance.

that was an error I missed after some tests, but it does the same thing even if I do not specify src

return false is not being used, because you're not returning the function's result. Use onsubmit="return search()"
